# Probability distribution of the subtraction of two dependent non-gaussian distributions

Tags: probability, self-study, correlation, independence, joint-distribution

I have two dependent,correlated non-gaussian random variable X and Y. I want to calculate probability distribution of Z=X-Y. For independent distribution, I know the equation is as follows,
[image]

What should be the equation for dependent random variables? Is there any crude way to know the approximate probabilities?

Thanks

Farhana

Comment: This sounds like a `self-study` question so please add the tag and let us know where you got stuck in the derivation of the density of $Z$.

Comment: I am sure which direction should I go. Some literature regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: (1) You have given the formula for the *sum* of two variables. (2) When they are dependent, use the joint density function: the principles do not change and neither does the formula, once you realize that $(x,y)\to f(x)f(y)$ actually is the joint density when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. (3) Specific examples have been worked out on this site: [please search it](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sum+dependent+distribution). (4) You can also pose this question as asking how to compute the distribution of the transformed variable $X-Y$: for that, use the usual change of variables formula.

Comment: Oh sorry. It should be fy(z+x). For dependent case i guess equation will be 
fx(x)*fy(z+x|x). This will be difficult to enumerate all the probabilities though.

Comment: I don't follow--it's a single integral, just as always.  It will be (in general) no more difficult than computing any sum by means of the formula you present.  In some cases it might even be simpler.

Comment: If the random variables are gaussian then calculation the mean and variance would have been enough considering the correlation. As this is non-gaussian, this means I have to enumerate all the probabilities as discrete random variables.

Comment: So far, all the information in your question indicates the variables are continuous, not discrete--but it doesn't matter, because then the solution is given by a sum.  It's exactly the same idea and uses similar techniques.  Do you have a particular bivariate distribution in mind? If so, it would be best to name it in your question. Have you researched the examples on this site? Many of them concern discrete distributions (such as a bivariate, correlated Poisson distribution).

Answer (score 4):

Building upon W. Huber's [sufficient] suggestions, the fact that the variables $X$ and $Y$ are dependent does neither modify nor complexify the derivation of the density of $Z=X-Y$. It is still a consequence of the principle of a [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables):

1. The pair $(X,Y)$ has density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$
2. The transform $$(x,y)\longrightarrow(x,x-y)$$ has its inverse equal to $$(x,z)\longrightarrow(x,z-x)$$ and the associated [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is$$J(x,z)=\left|\dfrac{d(x,y)}{d(x,z)}\right|=\left|\dfrac{d(x,z-x)}{d(x,z)}\right|$$ equal to $1$.
3. The [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables) formula provides the density of $(X,Z)$ as $$f_{X,Z}(x,z)=f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)J(x,z)$$
4. Marginalisation then returns the density of $Z$ as $$f_Z(z)=\int f_{X,Z}(x,z)\text{d}x=\int f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\text{d}x$$

Comment: +1 Something got messed up in the line about the Jacobian: the transformation does not involve $z$ at all, there's an isolated right parenthesis, and the expression inside the bars makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. My main concern is that I have the probability distribution function which comes from images. That is why they do not follow any precise distribution and as the values are dependent I need to compute the covariance terms. Calculating the covariance terms are really costly. I want an estimation of the probability distribution with very little computational overhead.

Comment: Your original question does not mention this issue, which anyway cannot be solved without further details about what you know about this distribution you mention.

Answer (score 0):

in such case, you will end up with a 2 dimensional fz(x,y) given that x and y are not independent (2 deg of freedom). you might dicretize and calcualte block by block the xy plane, as no elegant formula might exist. if the dependence realtionshio is polynomic you might apply various convolutional / Fourrier transform tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please suggest some literature for this topic?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Signals-Systems-2nd-Alan-Oppenheim/dp/0138147574?ie=UTF8&keywords=signal%20oppenheimer&qid=1463079171&ref_=sr_1_1&s=books&sr=1-1